# How to test my postfix+dovecot setup?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am creating one open source free docker mailserver at
https://github.com/kristijorgji/docker-mailserver

I have already some setup using postfix + dovecot + mysql for virtual users,domains but the problem is I don't know how to test the setup... WIP

I am running telnet and the message is queued fine
[image]

Then I get some error in `/var/log/error` from dovecot. Being here how to change this to /var/error/log/dovecot.error so I know is from them

```
==> /var/log/error <==
Jul 22 15:11:31 ae8be021402f dovecot[1321]: auth: Fatal: sql: Unknown database driver 'mysql'
Jul 22 15:11:31 ae8be021402f dovecot[1318]: master: Error: service(auth): command startup failed, throttling for 60.000 secs
Jul 22 15:11:31 ae8be021402f dovecot[1321]: lmtp(me@kristijorgji.com)<1642><3S3iFgO+2mJqBgAAAfX72A>: Error: auth-master: userdb lookup(me@kristijorgji.com): Disconnected unexpectedly
Jul 22 15:11:31 ae8be021402f dovecot[1321]: lmtp(1642): Error: lmtp-server: conn unix:pid=1639,uid=101 [1]: rcpt me@kristijorgji.com: Failed to lookup user me@kristijorgji.com: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
Jul 22 15:11:31 ae8be021402f dovecot[1321]: lmtp(me@kristijorgji.com)<1638><4FHMHxy+2mJmBgAAAfX72A>: Error: auth-master: userdb lookup(me@kristijorgji.com): Disconnected unexpectedly
Jul 22 15:11:31 ae8be021402f dovecot[1321]: lmtp(1638): Error: lmtp-server: conn unix:pid=1637,uid=101 [2]: rcpt me@kristijorgji.com: Failed to lookup user me@kristijorgji.com: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
```

doveconf -n

```
# 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.16 (09c29328)
# OS: Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit aarch64 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS fuse.grpcfuse
# Hostname: 6222782bccb4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Drafts
    name = Drafts
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Junk
    name = Junk
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Sent
    name = Sent
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Sent
    name = Sent Messages
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Trash
    name = Trash
  }
  prefix = 
  name = inbox
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service replication-notify-fifo {
  name = aggregator
}
service anvil-auth-penalty {
  name = anvil
}
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
  name = auth-worker
}
service {
  unix_listener {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
  }
  unix_listener {
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
    path = auth-userdb
  }
  user = dovecot
  name = auth
}
service config {
  name = config
}
service dict-async {
  name = dict-async
}
service dict {
  name = dict
}
service login/proxy-notify {
  name = director
}
service dns-client {
  name = dns-client
}
service doveadm-server {
  name = doveadm
}
service imap-hibernate {
  name = imap-hibernate
}
service {
  inet_listener {
    port = 143
    name = imap
  }
  inet_listener {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
    name = imaps
  }
  name = imap-login
}
service imap-urlauth {
  name = imap-urlauth-login
}
service imap-urlauth-worker {
  name = imap-urlauth-worker
}
service token-login/imap-urlauth {
  name = imap-urlauth
}
service imap-master {
  name = imap
}
service indexer-worker {
  name = indexer-worker
}
service indexer {
  name = indexer
}
service ipc {
  name = ipc
}
service {
  unix_listener {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
    path = /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp
  }
  name = lmtp
}
service log-errors {
  name = log
}
service old-stats-mail {
  name = old-stats
}
service {
  inet_listener {
    port = 0
    name = pop3
  }
  inet_listener {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
    name = pop3s
  }
  name = pop3-login
}
service login/pop3 {
  name = pop3
}
service replicator-doveadm {
  name = replicator
}
service stats-reader {
  name = stats
}
service submission {
  name = submission-login
}
service login/submission {
  name = submission
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.kristijorgji.com/cert.pem
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
protocol lmtp {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns-client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
}
protocol lda {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns-client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
}
protocol imap {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns-client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
}
protocol pop3 {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns-client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
}
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 3h
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = kristijorgji.com
myhostname = mail.kristijorgji.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_helo_timeout = 15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.kristijorgji.com/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.kristijorgji.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Comment: By default postfix logs to syslog not directly to a specific file - check your syslog config for the default location to store events if nothing specific has been configured for the messages postfix generates.

Comment: Ubuntu? Try `journalctl -u postfix@-.service`

Comment: Yes ubuntu `FROM ubuntu:22.04` . I get command not found `journalctl -u postfix@-.service
bash: journalctl: command not found
root@4299c9fd1ed6:/docker-data# 
`

Answer (score 0):

Since journalctl is missing, I assume **rsyslog** is present.

Postfix daemons log informations to a specific socket, usually located at:

```
/var/spool/postfix/dev/log
```

Check if this file is present.

**rsyslog** fetch logs from there. There should be a file in **rsyslog** configuration that tells it to connect to this socket. for Debian it is located at:

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/postfix.conf
```

Then, **rsyslog** will log the informations from this socket in a file corresponding to the prefix **mail** in its configuration file (somewhere in /etc/rsyslog.d).
Something like this:

```
*.*;mail,auth,authpriv.none     -/var/log/syslog
```

If all of the above things are OK but you still have issue. It is something else.

Comment: `tail -f /var/spool/postfix/dev/log
tail: cannot open '/var/spool/post`

Comment: `cat /etc/rsyslog.d/postfix.conf
# Create an additional socket in postfix's chroot in order not to break
# mail logging when rsyslog is restarted.  If the directory is missing,
# rsyslog will silently skip creating the socket.
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/spool/postfix/dev/log
`

Comment: /var/spool/postfix/dev/log is a socket and not meant to be opened. Looks like rsyslogd looks at the right socket. did you find any "mail" entries in /etc/rsyslogd.conf, for ubuntu it is /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf . under the RULES section of that file

Comment: `cat /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
cat: /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: `root@4299c9fd1ed6:/docker-data# cat /etc/rsyslogd.conf
cat: /etc/rsyslogd.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: assuming rsyslog is installed, you need to configure it properly. There is nothing that tells it to write mail.* log, that is why there is not any log entries on your system. Please reinstall rsylog (sudo apt install --reinstall rsyslog) and check if the required files are present. If not, you need to create it yourself: one way to do that is "apt download rsyslog", uncompress the deb file , uncompress the data.tar.xz file and there should be a rsyslog.conf you can copy.

Comment: Thanks. I did `apt install --reinstall rsyslog` and then telnet localhost 25, ehlo then checked all the mentioned files and logs stil they don't exist

Comment: then you need to create the rsyslog configuration file. fastest way is with  "apt download rsyslog" which will download the .deb file. Uncompress it and do as I described in my previous comment.

Comment: I fixed it. Issue was with postfix inside docker, found answer at `
# Use syslog-ng to get Postfix logs (rsyslog uses upstart which does not seem
# to run within Docker). Copied lines from here https://github.com/noteed/docker-postfix/blob/601366d38eaf1b0da38e9dd13c4ad48a85d3f3bb/Dockerfile#L36-L41
run apt-get install -q -y syslog-ng` then starting this service `service syslog-ng start` now I can finally see /var/log/mail being output which I think is a good start into troubleshooting this comlicated flow...

Comment: Ok so I get error logs now at /var/log/mail after telnet mail from , rcpt to `Jul 22 13:54:56 1ca0b84401fc postfix/lmtp[1501]: 8388528F52F: to=<me@kristijorgji.com>, relay=mail.kristijorgji.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=37, delays=37/0.02/0.02/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (host mail.kristijorgji.com[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 451 4.3.0 <me@kristijorgji.com> Temporary internal error (in reply to RCPT TO command))`

Comment: Now, please edit your post and show us the running configuration of postfix and dovecot. Just run the commands "postconf -n"  and "doveconf -n" as root and post the results. (-n means show the non-default values of your conf)

Comment: I updated, now have issues with dovecot ..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question: [doveadm](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm)

```
# test authentication
sudo doveadm auth test me@kristijorgji.com

# show informations about the user (user attributes)
sudo doveadm user -u me@kristijorgji.com

# show quota for a specific user
sudo doveadm quota get -u me@kristijorgji.com
```

If you intend to use **mysql driver**, make sure your configuration files has appropriate mysql *user_query* and *password_query*. I am assuming both are defined inside a file named */etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext* but the dovecot split config style usually uses */etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext* instead. In your case, follow the include path starting from */etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf* to find out.

According to the log of dovecot:

1/ You should install the **dovecot-mysql** package. Just "*apt install*" it.

There are some misconfigurations in your dovecot install. Good to know: user authentication is configured with **passdb{}** section while user attributes (including mail directory) is configured with the **userdb{}** section. Assuming you intend to use **mysql driver** for both:

2/  You passdb is OK:

```
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

3/ Your userdb uses to the wrong driver.

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

An example of userdb using mysql driver would look like this:

```
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

PS: The included configuration file */etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext* has more than enough informations to help you configure dovecot so refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I run the commands you sent `doveadm auth test me@kristijorgji.com
Password: 
passdb: me@kristijorgji.com auth succeeded
extra fields:
  user=me@kristijorgji.com`

Comment: `doveadm user -u me@kristijorgji.com
userdb: me@kristijorgji.com
  user      : me@kristijorgji.com
  uid       : 5000
  gid       : 5000
  home      : /var/mail/vhosts/kristijorgji.com/me`

Comment: `doveadm quota get -u me@kristijorgji.com
Fatal: Unknown command 'quota', but plugin quota exists. Try to set mail_plugins=quota` I think now emails are received fine actually. Only problem is I cannot connect with imap at port 143 as posted at https://serverfault.com/questions/1106336/thunderbird-wont-connect-to-dovecot-143-imap-certificate-ssl-error?noredirect=1#comment1444386_1106336